# Drupal Feed importers: Update Node values without needing to include all values in Feed

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

Currently when I try to import data through a feed, importer, if any field from the mappings is missing then the data for that field gets overwritten. This is despite of selecting

> Update existing nodes

or

> Replace existing nodes

Thus how can I ensure the data does not get overwritten with blank even though those mappings are provided but the column is not included in the csv.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to stick with the *Update existing nodes* to retain your existing content fields here.

The simplest way to prevent overwriting is to remove whatever mappings that aren't available in your CSV. If you have different CSVs with different available columns, cloning your current CSV feed importer and remove the columns from the new importer should accommodate different data update sources.

Comment: I would have taken this approach but in this case we have to set up these importers for the client who have to run them on their own later. So for a non technical admin, this may not work. Thanks.